# isn't so called push really pull?

Tags: push-notification

Ever since the introduction of push services in IOS I wonder how it works.

From what I found out the push function is basically an open connection that does not close serverside.

But mobiles are connecting at different points of the internet, the only way for a server to know where the mobile is connected is when the mobile tells the server where that it has changed location.

I read something about polling a connection so it stays open.

What advantage is there to manage and keep a changing open connection alive vs just checking if something is to pull?

Answer (score 1):

Internally yes, push is implemented by having your phone poll for new data. The thing that makes push notifications attractive is that they are routed over Apple's service and that has many advantages.

From the phone's point of view, it only has to poll from one service, which means it can conserve bandwidth and piggyback on the normal operations of keeping a cellphone online. That means a lot less battery is used, and you can do things like set your phone to only receive push notifications every half hour, which means that 29 minutes out of every half hour you can turn off the data connection.

From the server's point of view, you no longer need to cache messages or provide quality-of-service guarantees. If you want to send a push notification to a phone that's out of range of a cell-tower for a few minutes, you may need to store the message for a considerable amount of time until the phone comes back online. Apple handles all this for you, and lets your server just be in charge of creating notifications, not storing and relaying them.